# mod_wsgi, apache, bottle.py application

Tags: apache2, mod-wsgi, bottle

Currently, I am trying to have mod_wsgi run my bottle app but when I restart apache2, it keeps giving me the following error:

```
 File "/usr/local/www/documents/bottle.py"     
 from __future__ import with_statement        
 ImportError: No module named __future__
```

I have adapter.wsgi in the same directory as bottle (following code in adapter.wsgi):

```
import sys, os

sys.path = ['/usr/local/www/documents/']
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

import bottle
import webapp # This loads your application

application = bottle.default_app()
```

Answer (score 0):

This error only occurs when `mod_python` can't find `__future__.py`, which is a standard module in every Python installation, which suggests that either your installation is messed up or the `mod_python PythonPath` isn't quite right.